# Icons are moving with cursor

Tags: icons

In Ubuntu while using icons moving with cursor. What about the issue.

I have reinstalled 22.04.3 LTS and latest version also. I’m having issue.

I’m unable find the resolution of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be associated with this option in `Settings > Accessibility > Pointing & Clicking > Click Assist`

Ensure that this option is turned `off`

[image]

Comment: Its "Click Assist -- Off" Only. Its not Mouse issue. After reinstall Ubuntu OS while using 10 to 15 mins i'm unable to work if I click any icon it will more cursors. However mouse and keyboard working. OS is not responding i have restart and use . again after some time its same issue.